# bulk insert into sql server using package database/sql package

Tags: sql-server, go

I am trying to insert multiple records in sql server using Go. I am using below code. but getting this error "mssql: Incorrect syntax near '?'."  .

```
func BulkInsert(unsavedRows []*ExampleRowStruct) error {
    valueStrings := make([]string, 0, len(unsavedRows))
    valueArgs := make([]interface{}, 0, len(unsavedRows) * 3)
    for _, post := range unsavedRows {
        valueStrings = append(valueStrings, "(?, ?, ?)")
        valueArgs = append(valueArgs, post.Column1)
        valueArgs = append(valueArgs, post.Column2)
        valueArgs = append(valueArgs, post.Column3)
    }
    stmt := fmt.Sprintf("INSERT INTO my_sample_table (column1, column2, column3) VALUES %s", 
                        strings.Join(valueStrings, ","))
    _, err := db.Exec(stmt, valueArgs...)
    return err
}
```

Comment: MySQL uses `?` for parameters. MSSQL uses `@name`. See https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb#parameters for an example in Go.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. i update that to params and now it says mssql: Must declare the scalar variable "@name".
sorry if these are basic questions, am new to go and learning

Answer (score 0):

I don't know GO, but looking at your `stmt` value, I think your query format may be incorrect.

If you consider what you would enter directly as a SQL Server query, it would be something like:

```
INSERT INTO my_sample_table (column1, column2, column3) VALUES ('val1', 'val2', 'val3')
```

(assuming all the columns are varchar)

These could also be done using variables:

```
DECLARE @val1 varchar(4) = 'val1', @val2 varchar(4) = 'val2', @val3 varchar(4) = 'val3'
INSERT INTO my_sample_table (column1, column2, column3) VALUES (@val1, @val2, @val3)
```

From @adrian link, the example in your case would possibly be:

```
db.QueryContext(ctx, `INSERT INTO my_sample_table (column1, column2, column3) VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3);`, "val1", "val2", "val3")
```

Based on this - try the following:

```
stmt := fmt.Sprintf("INSERT INTO my_sample_table (column1, column2, column3) VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3)", strings.Join(valueStrings, ","))
```